# Select $pristine textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS. I'm trying to apply some validation and feedback to users. The way things are setup is a bit odd, so things such as `ng-required` don't seem to have an affect on the textareas they are applied to (guessing because they aren't actually within a `<form>`).

I am attempting to apply a class to change the `border-color` to red when one of the fields is not filled out.
Within my submit function, I am checking a flag. If it doesn't validate to true, then it runs this in the `else` block:

```
<div ng-repeat="keyWordForm in keyWordForm" class="fadeInBottom">
    {{keyWordForm.snippet}} <br>
    {{$scope.keywords}}
    <textarea style="{{keyWordForm.style}}" ng-required="'true'" class="{{keyWordForm.ourClass}} {{errorRequired}}" name="keyWordFormTextArea" ng-model="keyWordForm.data" ng-change="columnCount()"></textarea>

</div>
```

This applies a class `errorLine` using `{{errorRequired}}` within my html:

```
<textarea style="{{keyWordForm.style}}" class="{{keyWordForm.ourClass}} {{errorRequired}}" name="keyWordFormTextArea" ng-model="keyWordForm.data" ng-change="columnCount()"></textarea>
```

But this then applies the CSS to every textarea, rather than just the `$pristine` ones. **How would I apply the CSS to just the fields that have not yet been filled out?**

I've been trying to use something along the lines: `keywordFormTextArea.$pristine`, but can't find a valid way to use this to achieve my desired affects.

Desired effect:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my biggest part of the problem was `{{errorRequired}}` is essentially a global variable. So when I attempted to set that on the `undefined` textareas, it would set them on everything.
So I instead, I added it as a key to my object.

$scope.keyWordForm = [
    {snippet : "Enter Keywords: (separate line for each keyword)",
    style : "width:100%; height: 125px;",
    ourClass : "",
        keywordData : $scope.keyWord,
    errorRequired : $scope.errorRequired
    }
];

Then in my loop, I can just select in current index of my object and set the undefined there.

```
for(var i = 0; $scope.keyWordForm.length > i; i++){
    if(typeof $scope.keyWordForm[i].data == "undefined"){
        $scope.keyWordForm[i].errorRequired = "errorLine";
    }
}
```

And in my HTML, I just need to access that object.

```
class="... {{keyWordForm.errorRequired}}
```

Voila! This achieves the ability to have just the CSS for the `undefined` textareas applied.